# Hash metamask message

Tags: solidity, remix, javascript, hash

I have the following metamask message (type v4):

```
   const message = {
        domain: domain,
    
        // Defining the message signing data content.
        message: {
          Commit: {
            Commiter: taker,
            Type: 
              COMMIT_TYPE,
            Contract: WETH_CONTRACT_TESTNET, 
            Amount: commitedAmount
          },

          Consideration: 
            {
              ContractAddress: collection,
              TokenId: tokenId,
              Recipient: taker
            },
        },
       
        primaryType: 'Fragmentation',
        types: types
    }
```

And for verification purposes I wanted to hash it using ethers so that I can verify the message on chain. I did the following but it doesn't seem to work: `const hashedMessage = ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(message))`
It seems to fail because its expecting a string so I wanted to know if there's any way to hash an object so that I can verify it on chain.

Comment: try `ethers.utils.hexlify` to convert into bytes before sending it as `keccak256`